# How to get the length of the longest string in a nested list of strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-length

Newbie to Python here. I am trying to find the longest length of a value within a series of nested lists. Here is an example list type:

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]
```

The answer that I want here is `8`, but this could change if the list is updated.

When I use `print(len(tableData))` I get 3, the number of nested lists. I cannot get a loop working that solves this either.

Sorry for this being a really simple question, but I am at a loss.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you note, `len(tableData)` gives the number of elements of `tableData`. What you want is the max of the lengths of the elements *of the elements* of `tableData`:

```
l = max(len(x) for sublist in tableData for x in sublist)
```

```
>>> print(l)
8
```

Answer (score 4):

Iterate over each element and get its `len()` for comparison.

```
tableData = [['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]

maxCount = 0
for lst in tableData:
    for elem in lst:
        maxCount = max(maxCount, len(elem))

print(maxCount)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
8
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from itertools import chain

chain.from_iterable(tableData)
```

This now behaves as if you had one long list of single values, instead of a list of lists of values. Now it's trivial to find the longest item in that flattened list:

```
max(chain.from_iterable(tableData), key=len)
```

This returns `'cherries'`.

```
max(map(len, chain.from_iterable(tableData)))
```

This returns `8`.

Comment: If I may say so, this here is the fastest way to do it from all the versions on offer. It's about twice as fast as a double generator expression, and about three times as fast as two `for` loops. Not that it matters much for lists this size, but just saying…

Answer (score 2):

```
maxLength = 0
for row in tableData:
    maxRowElementLength = len(max(row, key=len))
    if maxLength < maxRowElementLength:
        maxLength = maxRowElementLength

print(maxLength)
```

Comment: Please edit your question so as to explain your code (you might also consider [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) explaining why it's useful to go beyond a code-only answer)

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data=np.array([['apples', 'oranges', 'cherries', 'banana'],
             ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Carol', 'David'],
             ['dogs', 'cats', 'moose', 'goose']]).reshape(-1)
>>> max(data,key=len)
'cherries'
>>> len(max(data,key=len))
8
```

Contributing my part to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
new_list = []
for sub_list in tableData:
    for item in sub_list:
        new_list.append(item)

max_element = max(new_list, key=len)

print(max_element) # this actually prints the item
print(len(max_element)) # this will give you the length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with loop...

```
l = 0 
for row in tableData: 
     for col in row: 
         l = len(col) if l < len(col) else l
```